# In 'The Scheme Programming Language' what is this strange 'let' form in '(reverse)'?

Tags: scheme, lisp, let

From [The Scheme Programming Language](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/), written by R. Kent Dybvig, I see this definition of [reverse](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/objects.html#./objects:s50):

```
procedure: (reverse list)
returns: a new list containing the elements of list in reverse order
libraries: (rnrs base), (rnrs)

reverse may be defined without error checks as follows.

(define reverse
  (lambda (ls)
    (let rev ([ls ls] [new '()])
      (if (null? ls)
          new
          (rev (cdr ls) (cons (car ls) new))))))

(reverse '()) <graphic> ()
(reverse '(a b c)) <graphic> (c b a)
```

What is going on with `rev` in this line?

```
(let rev ([ls ls] [new '()])
```

My understanding from the definition of [let](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding:s16) indicates that there can be no gap between the keyword `let` and the list of local bindings. So what is `rev` doing here between `let` and the bindings list?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I repent of my hastiness, looks like there's a link in there to a form called [named let](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/control.html#g100). Carry on everyone, crisis averted.